# How to solve equations symbolically in a loop in R?

Tags: r

I need to conduct Gaussian Maximum Likelihood Classification for 1000 data sets of two classes of bivariate Gaussian distributions with each 100 data points. 
Here is the code to create the data sets:

```
# mean vector for two classes
mean1<-c(70,130) ; mean2<-c(148,160)
# covariance matrix for two classes
cov1<-matrix(c(784,-546,-546,900),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
cov2<-matrix(c(484,285.1,285.1,324),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

 library(MASS)
# Number of samples
nrs <- 1000
# sample size
ss  <- 100
# number of dimensions
d   <- length(mean1)
set.seed(1)
# generation of bivariate normal random variables based on mean vector and covariance matrix for each class
refdata_1 <- replicate(nrs,matrix(mvrnorm(ss, mu = mean1, Sigma = cov1 ),ncol = d,nrow = ss),simplify=FALSE)
refdata_2 <- replicate(nrs,matrix(mvrnorm(ss, mu = mean2, Sigma = cov2 ),ncol = d,nrow = ss),simplify=FALSE)
# calculation of mean vector for each sample of random reference data
mean_refdata_1 <- lapply(refdata_1,colMeans)
mean_refdata_2 <- lapply(refdata_2,colMeans)
# calculation of covariance matrix for each sample of random reference data
cov_refdata_1 <- lapply(refdata_1,cov)
cov_refdata_2 <- lapply(refdata_2,cov)
```

Now, I need to plot the decision boundary between the two classes for each of the 1000 data sets (thus 1000 decision boundaries).

Here is the decision equation (if you wonder where the ln p(class) part is, both classes have same probability and thus cancel each other out):

This is the vector of the data points:

```
x = vector(SR,var('a,b'))
```

Here is the decision equation (if you wonder where the ln p(class) part is, both classes have same probability and thus cancel each other out):

```
decision1 =-0.5*log(det(cov1))-0.5*((x-mean1)*cov1.inverse()*(x-mean1)) 
decision2 =-0.5*log(det(cov2))-0.5*((x-mean2)*cov2.inverse()*(x-mean2))
```

If `decision1(data point) > decision2(data point)`, then the data point belongs to class 1. In order to get the decision boundary, `decision1 - decision2 == 0`. The data points are RBG images. Thus, a in the data vector x is 0:255. I solve the equation for b:

```
solve(decision1-decision2==0,b)
```

In R, that looks for the original data set like this:

```
m_1<-c(70,130) ; m_2<-c(148,160)
covma_1<-matrix(c(784,-546,-546,900),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
covma_2<-matrix(c(484,285.1,285.1,324),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
library(rSymPy)  
c11 <- Var("c11")
c12 <- Var("c12")
c13 <- Var("c13")
c14 <- Var("c14")
sympy("covma_1 = Matrix([[c11,c12], [c13,c14]])")
a <- Var("a")
b <- Var("b")
sympy("x = Matrix([a,b])")
m11 <- Var("m11")
m12 <- Var("m12")
sympy("m_1 = Matrix([m11,m12])")

sympy("covma_1=covma_1.subs(c11,784)")
sympy("covma_1=covma_1.subs(c12,-546)")
sympy("covma_1=covma_1.subs(c13,-546)")
sympy("covma_1=covma_1.subs(c14,900)")
sympy("m_1=m_1 .subs(m11,70)")
sympy("m_1=m_1 .subs(m12,130)")

first  <-sympy("-0.5*log(covma_1.det())")
second <-sympy("-0.5*((x-m_1).T*covma_1.inv()*(x-m_1))")

second<-gsub("\\[","",second)
second<-gsub("\\]","",second)

c21 <- Var("c21")
c22 <- Var("c22")
c23 <- Var("c23")
c24 <- Var("c24")
sympy("covma_2 = Matrix([[c21,c22], [c23,c24]])")
m21 <- Var("m21")
m22 <- Var("m22")
sympy("m_2 = Matrix([m21,m22])")

sympy("covma_2=covma_2.subs(c21,484)")
sympy("covma_2=covma_2.subs(c22,285.1)")
sympy("covma_2=covma_2.subs(c23,285.1)")
sympy("covma_2=covma_2.subs(c24,324)")
sympy("m_2=m_2.subs(m21,148)")
sympy("m_2=m_2.subs(m22,160)")

third  <-sympy("-0.5*log(covma_2.det())")
fourth <-sympy("-0.5*((x-m_2).T*covma_2.inv()*(x-m_2))")

fourth<-gsub("\\[","",fourth)
fourth<-gsub("\\]","",fourth)

class1 <- paste(c(first,second),collapse="")
class2 <- paste(c(third,fourth),collapse="")

sympy(paste(c("hm=solve(",class2,"-","(",class1,")",",b)"), collapse = ""))
```

As you can see, I use very nasty string operations to parse into sympy. Anyway, after solving for b in sympy, I stuck and don't know how to get numeric values. Can somebody tell me how to solve symbolically for b and plot it in a loop for 1000 data sets? I m also open for non-symbolic approaches.

Any help is appreciated!